# SharePoint 2010 Webfrontend serer showing diffrent result

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

My client has two SharePoint WFE in a farm. While we are trying to access the SharePoint portal with server name, we have encountered one issue with server 1. The issue is on a list page, a user is not seeing an "**Add new Item**" option while on other server he has the option on same list.

Please suggest what could be reason.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your accessing one of the WFE's through an extended zone which has specific policies set to the accounts, for instance deny write.

Comment: Hi WIctor, I got your point but we are not having server specific policy to any user.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the Timer service is running on all servers in your farm.  After that, verify which Web App/Zones the user might be hitting based on the URL being used to access each WFE.  You can find this info in Central Administration - System Settings - Alternate Access Mappings.  Make sure that both URLs the user is using do in fact go to the same Web Application.